# Flutter Error output from Xcode build after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I tried so many flutter clean and pod file deleting ios folder etc almost all but still getting the error.

Here is what I get after running the flutter run.

```
            Running pod install...                                              7.8s
        Running Xcode build...                                                  
        └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5.3s
        Xcode build done.                                           44.2s
        Failed to build iOS app
        Error output from Xcode build:
        ↳
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.714 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed
            project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.714 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only
            the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed
            project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only
            the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
            membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
            membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only
            the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            2020-11-22 04:23:48.715 xcodebuild[18120:174376] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a
            malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
            ** BUILD FAILED **


        Xcode's output:
        ↳
            While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:
            In file included from <module-includes>:1:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:13:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterCodecs.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #include "FlutterCodecs.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    <Flutter/FlutterCodecs.h>
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:14:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlatformViews.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #include "FlutterPlatformViews.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    <Flutter/FlutterPlatformViews.h>
            While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:
            In file included from <module-includes>:1:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:14:
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlatformViews.h:10:9: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterCodecs.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #import "FlutterCodecs.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    <Flutter/FlutterCodecs.h>
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlatformViews.h:11:9: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #import "FlutterMacros.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    <Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
            While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:
            In file included from <module-includes>:1:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:15:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterTexture.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #include "FlutterTexture.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    <Flutter/FlutterTexture.h>
            While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:
            In file included from <module-includes>:1:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:15:
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterTexture.h:11:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
            #include "FlutterMacros.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated Flutter, Cocoapods and Xcode at the same time. After that, none of my flutter projects were building for iOS.

What worked for me -> Run this in your project:

`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

flutter run -> app running again!